# React.js useEffect with nested async functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the common warning displaying upon loading of my web app but never again...

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

EDIT****
It is caused by this chunk of code. I have narrowed it down to one function. It blows up when I try to setMoisture state. I am not sure why.

```
function getData (){
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get-value").then((response) => {
        const recievedData = response.data;
        const dataValue = recievedData.map((val) => {
            return [val.value]
        })
        if (loading === true){
            setLoading(false);
        }
        return parseInt(dataValue);
    }).then((resp)=>setMoisture(resp))
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (moisture === "initialState"){
        getData();
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: I think I have narrowed down the issue to within the getData function.

Comment: what does `setMoisture()` do? Any components used there?

Comment: Yes it is a state variable [moisture, setMoisture] = useState['']

Comment: I have eddited my previous post. This is what is causing the issue. Any idea how to fix this? I am calling setLoading also which is a state variable and no issues

Comment: Have you seen this question yet? I think your situation is similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component Make sure to return a function that does the cleanup towards the end of `useEffect`. Something like `return () => { ... };`

Comment: Thank you!!! This is the solution. I will post below.

Comment: Solution is identical to this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer here (based from the comments) for completeness.

Basically, use local variables and cleanup function towards the end of useEffect(). Using this as reference:

[Similar situation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)