# reactjs unmounted components, viral

Tags: reactjs

I searched for all possible pages but I could not solve this problem. I also tried with some modules, with an abort controller and all other things but to this day I don't know what is the proper way and how to solve this problem about unmounted components. I am working with functional components. This is my code:

```
  const [visitorsNumber, setVisitorsNumber] = useState(0);
  const [loggedList, setLoggedList] = useState([]);

  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.open();
    socket.on('visiotrsnumber', (data) => {
       if (mounted === true) setVisitorsNumber(data)
    })
    socket.on('loggedlist', (data) => {
      if (mounted === true) setLoggedList(data)
    })

    return () => {
      socket.close();
      setMounted(false);
    }

  }, [loggedList, visitorsNumber]);
```

Can anyone explain to me why this error occurs and what is the solution to this?

Error log:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

When i delete this code i dont getting error.

Comment: The error occurs because you are using setMounted(false), the state can't be modified when component is unmounted

Comment: Can you please give me some example code or something? Just need the correct way to do this, this killing me from start...

Comment: Can you actually show the error trace and possibly modify the question title - it's vague.

Comment: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-hooks. Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: The example from @lissettdm is working :) Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The state can't be modified when component is unmounted. I don't see any reason to use setMounted(false) when component is unmounted, also the `useEffect` callback is called when component is mounted, so you don't need to check that, but if you need it to, you can use `useRef` instead:

```
const mounted = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
    socket.open();
    socket.on('visiotrsnumber', (data) => {
       if (mounted.current === true) setVisitorsNumber(data)
    })
    socket.on('loggedlist', (data) => {
      if (mounted.current === true) setLoggedList(data)
    })

    return () => {
      socket.close();
      mounted.current=false;
    }

  }, [loggedList, visitorsNumber]);
```

Comment: This example is working for me, is this the best way to handle this error? Thanks 4 help :)

Comment: Yes, because you can't update the state when component is unmounted

Comment: Thanks very much 4 help:)

Comment: I still cant solve this problem brother, i updated my full code in comment and thanks for help

Comment: Are you using const mounted = useRef(true);?? because you can't update the state when component is unmounted

Comment: I post my full code up with fetches and everything, and i used your example but i still got this error on multiple pages so i need best solution for this so i can use it in feature.. And thanks alot for help.

Comment: any help for this>

Comment: Do you need to use mounted for some reasons? because it is an antipattern, check this: https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html, use it only if it is neccessary

Comment: I dont need , but i dont know how to solve this error with unmounted because when i start to switch fast pages in navigation i got error in multiple pages. Example if i got in users and fast when he didnt even load posts i change in posts i got error.. Any example u can give me with my code up?