# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. How to use did mount

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router

### How to use Did mount ?

My code has a problem at the time of login, when I change the screens and the auth is done. I don't know what the solution is but I think that by mistake it was the did mount that I don't know how to use: D I looked for the did mount but I don't know how to use it even more, I have to find out how it works

### PROBLEM

```
ERROR Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Home (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    (...)
    in StackNavigator (at MainStack.routes.js:11)
    in HomeStack (at App.js:32)
```

### APP.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import MainStack from "./Routes/MainStack.routes";
import HomeStack from "./Routes/HomeStack.routes";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import Load from "./Components/Load";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export default function App() {
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  async function onAuthStateChanged(userLoged) {
    setUser(userLoged);
    if (userLoged) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("lolguide@user", JSON.stringify(userLoged));
    }
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
  }, []);

  if (initializing) {
    return <Load />;
  }

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MainStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <HomeStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

### HomeStack.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Load from "../Components/Load";
import MainStackScreen from "../Routes/MainStack.routes";
import Home from "../Pages/Home/index";
import Profile from "../Pages/Profile";
import Champ from "../Pages/Champ/index";

const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStackScreens = () => (
  <MainStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
    <MainStack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={Home} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Loading" component={Load} />
    <MainStack.Screen
      name="LoginHome"
      component={MainStackScreen}
    />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile}/>
    <MainStack.Screen name="Champ" component={Champ}/>
  </MainStack.Navigator>
);

export default HomeStackScreens;
```

### MainStack.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Login from "../Pages/Login/index";
import SignUp from "../Pages/SignUp/index";
import Load from "../Components/Load";
import Home from "../Routes/HomeStack.routes";

const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStack = () => (
  <MainStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
    <MainStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="Loading" component={Load} />
    <MainStack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={Home} />
  </MainStack.Navigator>
);

export default HomeStack;
```

### Home

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container } from "./styles";
import Header from "../../Components/Header";
import Load from "../../Components/Load";
import ChampCard from "../../Components/ChampCard";
import { FlatList, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Home = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [champs, setChamps] = useState([]);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function navegar(tela, props) {
    navigation.navigate(tela, {item: JSON.stringify(props)});
  }

  async function getData() {
    await fetch(
      "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.10.1/data/pt_BR/champion.json"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setChamps(Object.values(json.data)));

    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Load />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Header type="NormalHeader"/>
        {champs.length > 0 ? (
          <FlatList
            data={champs}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
            renderItem={(item) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navegar("Champ", item)}>
                <ChampCard item={item}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 65 }}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          />
        ) : (
          <Load />
        )}
      </Container>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#000"/>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

### Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Image, Dimensions, PixelRatio, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {
  Container,
  Logo,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  Button,
  ButtonArea,
  ImageBox,
  ViewAbsolute,
} from "./styles";
import Load from "../../Components/Load";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";

const widthPercentageToDP = (widthPercent) => {
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(
    (screenWidth * parseFloat(widthPercent)) / 100
  );
};

const heightPercentageToDP = (heightPercent) => {
  const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(
    (screenHeight * parseFloat(heightPercent)) / 100
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  linearGradient: {
    height: heightPercentageToDP("120%"),
    flex: 1,
  },
});

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleSend = () => {
    if (email && password) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then( () => {
          navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.code) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        });
      setIsLoading(false);
    } else {
      alert("Preencha os campos!");
    }
  };

  const handleRegisterNavigate = () => {
    navigation.navigate("SignUp");
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Load />;
  }

  return (
    <ViewAbsolute>
      <Container>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={["#C28F2C", "#000", "#004840"]}
          style={styles.linearGradient}
          start={{ x: 0, y: -0.2 }}
          end={{ x: 0, y: 1.2 }}
        >
          <Logo>
            <Image
              source={require("../../Assets/lolGuideIcon.png")}
              style={{ height: 75, width: 80 }}
              resizeMode="stretch"
            />
          </Logo>
          <Text>O primeiro passo para se tornar um campeão é a iniciativa</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Email"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            margin_top="50px"
            value={email}
            onChangeText={(t) => setEmail(t)}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Senha"
            margin_top="5px"
            secureTextEntry
            value={password}
            onChangeText={(t) => setPassword(t)}
          />
          <ButtonArea>
            <Button width="80px" margin_top="20px" onPress={handleSend}>
              <Text>Entrar</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              width="110px"
              margin_top="10px"
              onPress={handleRegisterNavigate}
            >
              <Text>Registrar</Text>
            </Button>
          </ButtonArea>
          <ImageBox>
            <Image
              source={require("../../Assets/Pyke-transparente.png")}
              style={{
                height: 230,
                width: 260,
              }}
            />
          </ImageBox>

          <StatusBar style="auto" backgroundColor="transparent" />
        </LinearGradient>
      </Container>
    </ViewAbsolute>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: i have updated now

Comment: Share your Home component

Comment: Does it is that ?

Comment: I think you can find a solution from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FOUND IT!!!
The problem was because I was navigating to other screen while my useEffect was working
so: I remove the navigate in Login and SignUp screen and that works

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Image, Dimensions, PixelRatio, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {
  Container,
  Logo,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  Button,
  ButtonArea,
  ImageBox,
  ViewAbsolute,
} from "./styles";
import Load from "../../Components/Load";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";

const widthPercentageToDP = (widthPercent) => {
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(
    (screenWidth * parseFloat(widthPercent)) / 100
  );
};

const heightPercentageToDP = (heightPercent) => {
  const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(
    (screenHeight * parseFloat(heightPercent)) / 100
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  linearGradient: {
    height: heightPercentageToDP("120%"),
    flex: 1,
  },
});

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleSend = () => {
    if (email && password) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        //.then( () => {
        //  navigation.navigate("HomeScreen"); REMOVE THIS BLOCK
        //  setIsLoading(false);
        //})
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.code) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        });
      setIsLoading(false);
    } else {
      alert("Preencha os campos!");
    }
  };

  const handleRegisterNavigate = () => {
    navigation.navigate("SignUp");
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Load />;
  }

  return (
    <ViewAbsolute>
      <Container>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={["#C28F2C", "#000", "#004840"]}
          style={styles.linearGradient}
          start={{ x: 0, y: -0.2 }}
          end={{ x: 0, y: 1.2 }}
        >
          <Logo>
            <Image
              source={require("../../Assets/lolGuideIcon.png")}
              style={{ height: 75, width: 80 }}
              resizeMode="stretch"
            />
          </Logo>
          <Text>O primeiro passo para se tornar um campeão é a iniciativa</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Email"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            margin_top="50px"
            value={email}
            onChangeText={(t) => setEmail(t)}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Senha"
            margin_top="5px"
            secureTextEntry
            value={password}
            onChangeText={(t) => setPassword(t)}
          />
          <ButtonArea>
            <Button width="80px" margin_top="20px" onPress={handleSend}>
              <Text>Entrar</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              width="110px"
              margin_top="10px"
              onPress={handleRegisterNavigate}
            >
              <Text>Registrar</Text>
            </Button>
          </ButtonArea>
          <ImageBox>
            <Image
              source={require("../../Assets/Pyke-transparente.png")}
              style={{
                height: 230,
                width: 260,
              }}
            />
          </ImageBox>

          <StatusBar style="auto" backgroundColor="transparent" />
        </LinearGradient>
      </Container>
    </ViewAbsolute>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onAuthStateChanged` function makes the dependencies of `useEffect()` Hook change on every render. Move it inside the `useEffect` callback. Alternatively, you can wrap the definition of `onAuthStateChanged` in its own `useCallback()` Hook.

The updated code for `App.js`:-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import MainStack from "./Routes/MainStack.routes";
import HomeStack from "./Routes/HomeStack.routes";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import Load from "./Components/Load";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export default function App() {
  
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged((userLogged) => {
      setUser(userLogged);
      if (userLogged) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("lolguide@user", JSON.stringify(userLogged));
      }
      if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
    });
  }, [initializing]);

  if (initializing) {
    return <Load />;
  }

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MainStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <HomeStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try closing and restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak usually when be will happened , you in the asynchronous function after that your component was unmounted , update your states. you are able to handle it by **useRef** (as one of the solutions) , So try followings this , i hope this help you:

**Home**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container } from "./styles";
import Header from "../../Components/Header";
import Load from "../../Components/Load";
import ChampCard from "../../Components/ChampCard";
import { FlatList, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Home = () => {
  const isMounted = React.useRef(null);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [champs, setChamps] = useState([]);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function navegar(tela, props) {
    navigation.navigate(tela, {item: JSON.stringify(props)});
  }

  async function getData() {
    await fetch(
      "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.10.1/data/pt_BR/champion.json"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
          if (isMounted.current)
             setChamps(Object.values(json.data)));
      }
    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;

    getData();

    return ()=> {
        isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Load />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Header type="NormalHeader"/>
        {champs.length > 0 ? (
          <FlatList
            data={champs}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
            renderItem={(item) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navegar("Champ", item)}>
                <ChampCard item={item}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 65 }}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          />
        ) : (
          <Load />
        )}
      </Container>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#000"/>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Also if you see this warning whenever , you can use the approach for handle that.

Comment: I have stop to seeing this error for the first time, but when I signout and log in again the error comes again, how can I handle that

Comment: Did you received the same warning or the warning has difference ? also did you checking out the Login screen?

Comment: The same warning message Could you check my login screen ?