# useEffect in child component pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following two components.

```
<Foo>
  <Bars/>
<Foo>
```

When `Foo` is called the console shows:

```
call Bar useEffect
Warning: Cant perform a React state update on an unmounted component...
call Foo useEffect
call Bar useEffect again
```

Here's the codepen but it doesn't generate the same warning which could be because its in development mode on my local. It does show null prints though.

https://codepen.io/rsgmon/pen/OJmPGpa

Is this component structure, with useEffect in each component, not recommended/allowed?
If it's ok what do I need to change to avoid the warning?

Comment: Show some code? It sounds like you may not have a proper destructor (return value that cleans up) in the useEffect. - Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: @Nikki9696 Coded added and thanks for the suggested link. I did try the suggested fixes but still get the error.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I don't see Bars mounted? Like, there's no element in here, just a stringify. - never mind, I can read

Comment: Okay, I see your sample has Bars nested in Foo, but the Foo element is also appending Bars. I can't test this since you have references to some API though. I'm still slightly confused as I don't see the useEffect returning anything. If you can pop it up on a pen or something with a fake api, folks can debug it...?

Comment: @Nikki9696 https://codepen.io/rsgmon/pen/OJmPGpa
Probably because I'm running in development mode on my local it shows the warning whereas on codepen it doesn't. Thanks for any assistance or insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely occurring because a state update to `Foo` triggers a re-render, causing `Bars` to unmount and remount.

Then the original `Bars` API request completes and it attempts to update state on the component that isn't mounted anymore, hence the warning.

You can fix it by declaring a variable inside the effect that's initially false and setting it to true in the effect's cleanup function:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let unmounted = false;
  
  doSomeAsynchronousStuff()
    .then( result => {

      if (unmounted) {
        return; // not mounted anymore. bail.
      }

      // do stuff with result

    })

  return () => unmounted = true; // cleanup gets called on un-mount
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks @ray-hatfield, adding your suggested code into Bars did it. I'll have to read about clean up on `useEffect` as I'm guessing `unmounted` isn't a special variable to useEffect.

Comment: There's nothing special about the name unmounted. Call it whatever you want.