# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component , method needs to run only one time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch the advertisers list when the component mounts, but it is causing me memory leak,
Any suggestions ? i'll be grateful :)

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const list = await Api.listAdvertisers();
      setAdvertisers(list);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: How many elements are in the fetched list in a single request?

Comment: around a hundred @AdilBimzagh

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. The memory leak must be coming from other code you've not shown.

Comment: @Andy when i comment that code the error disappears :/ , guess that's what's causing the leak
ps : i'm using material-table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-hooks. Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: @skyboyer Yessss !!!
Thank you very much !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your fetchData function on main scope and you can check the function if it is called or not by declaring a didMount variable in useEffect scope.

```
const didMount = useRef(false);

const fetchData = async () => {
      const list = await beeswaxService.listAdvertisers();
      setAdvertisers(list);
      return;
    };

useEffect(() => {
    if(!didMount.current){
       didMount.current = true;
       fetchData();
    }
    
  }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the function inside the useEffect is causing memory leak, try this?

```
const fetchData = async () => {
      const list = await beeswaxService.listAdvertisers();
      setAdvertisers(list);
      return;
    };

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Still same issue :/, but thanks for the effort

Comment: if setAdvertisers is changing the state it can cause infinite loop. State change making effect run and the effect changing the state indefinitely.,

Comment: @HarshaLimaye any suggestions please ?

Comment: @HarshaLimaye that would only happen if that changing state is part of the useEffect dependencies which in this case, is it is not