# UseEffect can't performe state update

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, state, use-effect

I am getting this UseEffct error that causes my window to render an empty page
error ="Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

my Component Code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { instance } from "../Data/axios";

const Row = ({ title, fetchURL }) => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  //  A snippet of code that runs on a certain condition
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const data = await instance.get(fetchURL);
      setMovies(data.data.results);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchURL]);

  const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

  console.log(movies);
  return (
    <div className="rows">
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <div className="rows_poster">
        {movies.map((movie) => {
          <div key={movie.id}>
            <img src={`${base_url}${movie.poster_path}`} />
          </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Row;
```

Comment: What did you find from researching the error yourself? [Stack overflow search for this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Can%27t+perform+a+React+state+update+on+an+unmounted+component)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-hooks. Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442582/react-hooks-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: I have tried unsubscribing but its working

Comment: @BrianThompson are you going to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true;
  async function fetchData(){
    const data = await instance.get(fetchURL);
    if (mounted) {
      setMovies(data.data.results);
    }
  };
  fetchData();
  return ()=> {mounted = false}
}, []);
```